# ReasonML on VSCode - "Go to Definition" from inside *.ml library file doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying out ReasonML on VSCode. But have a little problem with "Go to Definition" feature.

From a SomeFile.re I can right click -> "Go to Definition" on a standard library function (in this case `Format.printf(...)`) and it will jump to the definition as I expect (in this case `./node_modules/bs-platform/lib/ocaml/format.ml`)

But inside format.ml, "Go to Definition" doesn't work for me. So I can't explore the underlying function further. In this case, in format.ml, `printf` calls `fprintf`. When I try to "Go to Definition on `fprintf`, it says "No definition found for fprintf"

Does anyone have a pointer for me to make this work?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in something or other. Just in case others are looking: https://github.com/reasonml-editor/vscode-reasonml/issues/136

Comment: Thanks! I missed the github issue discussion. I'll follow up there.